# How do i get the current date every time i send a report to server (android)?

Tags: android, api, server, retrofit2

I send a report to server with this method

```
public void sendReport(Activity activity, final Report report) {

    Interface communicator = RestAdapterHelper.getInstance().createAdapter(activity);


    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
    report.setDateTime(formattedDate);
    report.getDateTime().equals(formattedDate);



    Call<ServerResponse> caller = communicator.sendReport(
            Functions.getInstance().getReportUrl(activity),
            report.getId(),
            report.getDeviceId(),
            report.getCampaignId(),
            report.getBranchId(),
            report.getDateTime()
    );
```

}

I add the data with this method

```
public static void addReport(Report report) {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
    report.setDateTime(formattedDate);
    report.getDateTime().equals(formattedDate);


    String query = "INSERT INTO reports (id,device_id,campaign_id,branch_id,,datetime,is_reported) VALUES(null,'"
            + report.getDeviceId() + "','"
            + report.getCampaignId() + "','"
            + report.getBranchId() + "','"
            + report.getDateTime() + "','0');";

    database.execSQL(query);

    resultSet = database.rawQuery("SELECT * from reports"/* where is_reported = 0"*/, null);
    while (resultSet.moveToNext()) {
        //Get the last inserted ID
        latestReportId = resultSet.getString(0);
    }
    report.setId(latestReportId);
    new Communicator().sendReport(activity, report);
}
```

And this is the method i create the database

```
 private void setUpDatabase() {


    database = openOrCreateDatabase("user_reports", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reports(id integer primary key autoincrement,device_id VARCHAR,campaign_id INTEGER, branch_id INTEGER, datetime TIMESTAMP, is_reported INTEGER);";
    database.execSQL(query);
}
```

Every data is sent to server except the date ,it keeps displaying to server 12/12/2019 15:42:19. Can you please tell me what am i doing wrong ?Why can't i change the date?

Comment: you're adding the date to database via value from method getDateTime(), could you share the code from that method?

Comment: I get the values from a json file .I have created a model class called Report with the json attributes and the getDateTime() is declared there with the getter and setter methods.

Comment: do you know what i do wrong?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0):

You can get like below, please check this and pass formattedDate to the server and as well as in a database . It's helpful.

```
 public static void getCurrentTimeUsingDate() {
        Date date = new Date();
        String strDateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a";
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(strDateFormat);
        String formattedDate= dateFormat.format(date);       
        Toast.makeText(this, formattedDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```